# how to send messages all channel

Tags: python, discord.py

i want send messages to all channel that bot has joined

```py
def check(cnt): 
    while 1:  
        if hash_origin != str(subprocess.check_output(["md5sum",filename])[:-len(filename)-3])[2:-1] :
            print("file destroyed alert!")
            alert = 1
        sleep(0.5)
```

i want send message to all discord channel that bot joined when specific file's hash result is different from original.
i know how to send respond message to channel

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

using this code, right?
but i want to send message to all of the channel that bot has joined when some event has happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send a message to every channel that the bot is in, you must do:

```
@client.event
async def foo(bar): # change this to the event in which you wish to call it from
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.send(messagedata) # change messagedata to whatever it is you want to send.
```

Comment: when using this code directly, error has occurred AttributeError: 'CategoryChannel' object has no attribute 'send'  i'm using code like this.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def foo(bar): # change this to the event in which you wish to call it from
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.send(messagedata) # change messagedata to whatever it is you want to send.
```

when using this code directly, error has occurred

```
AttributeError: 'CategoryChannel' object has no attribute 'send'
```

because "guild.channels" object have list of "all channels"(including text,voice,etc..) that bot has joined.
so, if i want send text message to channel, using "guild.text_channels" instead.
anyway, thanks to Tylerr !!